# PrometheusScrapeEndpoint error at runtime on jhipster project

Tags: java, spring, jhipster, prometheus

I am moving some code from an old jhipster project to a new one. I am a Java notice. I fixed all the compile time errors but when I run maven I get this runtime errors. Does anyone have any suggestions how to fix these errors.

```
2020-05-07 17:53:28.099 ERROR 3770 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.test.TestApp]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.prometheus.PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration$PrometheusScrapeEndpointConfiguration
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.export.prometheus.PrometheusScrapeEndpoint
```

```
<spring-boot.version>2.2.5.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
```

Comment: Which version of spring boot are you using? What did you change in your dependencies in pom.xml ?

Comment: I added prometheus dependencies from the other project into my pom.xml to no effect.